# Xamarin forms - suddenly I get error XA0137

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have an app in Xamarin Forms and I'm using VS Community 2022 (version 17.0.4). I test my app on a physical Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 11.
I was programming my app and suddenly out of the blue I get an error when I want to deploy my app after a small code change.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     XA0137: The 'run-as' command failed with 'run-as: couldn't stat
> /data/user/0/com.app.local: No such file or directory '. Fast
> Deployment is not currently supported on this device. Please file an
> issue with the exact error message using the 'Help->Send
> Feedback->Report a Problem' menu item in Visual Studio or
> 'Help->Report a Problem' in Visual Studio for Mac. Please set the
> 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true' to disable Fast
> Deployment in the Visual Studio project property pages, or edit the
> project file in a text editor.

This is very interesting since it worked 10 seconds before I got this error, so something else is wrong here. I reverted my code changes without any success. I also disabled Fast Deployment, in which case the error disappears but the deployment is still not happening and no other errors are shown. VS is just not deploying for some reason. This leads me to believe something else is wrong.

Anyone any ideas?

UPDATE: I deployed the app on another device (a tablet) and that works, so the issue should be with my phone.

Comment: have you tried - deleting the app, rebooting the device/emulator, restarting VS, rebooting your PC, cleaning your solution... these are all pretty common troubleshooting steps when faced with a weird build/deployment error

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention everything: I deleted the app, restarting VS, rebooted the PC, rebooted the device, cleaning the solution (and all kinds of combinations of this), repaired VS and lastly I also removed the entire solution and cloned it again to my PC.

Comment: I added an update: I deployed the app on another device (a tablet) and that works, so the issue should be with my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error while trying out a new MAUI project. My first deployment (through VS) went ok, and the application was functioning fine.
It's when I uninstalled the app manually from my device, and then tried to redeploy it with VS that I started to get this error.

---

> XA0137: The 'run-as' command failed with 'run-as: couldn't stat /data/user/0/com.companyname.mauiappshell: No such file or directory

---

The only way that I could bypass this deployment error was to manually rename the **ApplicationId** from within the MAUI project file.

So, if your application id is like

```
<ApplicationId>com.companyname.appname</ApplicationId>
```

rename it to something like

```
<ApplicationId>com.companyname.1.appname</ApplicationId>
```

and try to re-deploy the app to your device.

Comment: Great! This works in Xamarin as well. It's called package in Android (for the people that read this) and can be found in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Huawei.
I think this is due to the fact that one phone can have several users. Where each user has their own individual phone settings, including a set of installed applications. In this regard, you need to delete the application in the settings in the following way: “Settings” - “Applications”, then select your application, then “About the application” - “Uninstall for all users”. In this case, the application will be uninstalled correctly. And subsequent installation will not require any preparatory steps.